# Core data one-to-many relationship and Table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

Well, I have been beating my head over this one for some time now, definitely over a week and I just don't know where I am going wrong. Your help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the app idea. I have two entities modeled in core data. The Tycoon entity has a one to many relationship with Speech, so each Tycoon is capable of having more than one speech.
In the Tycoon entity, the relationship is titled 'TycoonToSpeech' and in the Speech entity, the relationship to Tycoon is titled 'SpeechToTycoon' (this is not a one to many relationship).

Problem 1: I thought I had created my relationships in the appdelegate.m file correctly, but I am not sure. Here is the code in my appdelegate to generate content. Should I do anything more with the NSMutableSets???

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];


NSEntityDescription *tycoonEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tycoon" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSManagedObject *steve = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[tycoonEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];

[steve setValue:@"Steve Jobs" forKey:@"Name"];
int orgId = [steve hash];
[steve setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orgId] forKey:@"Id"];

NSManagedObject *warren = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[tycoonEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[warren setValue:@"Warren Buffet" forKey:@"Name"];
int orgId2 = [warren hash];
[warren setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orgId2] forKey:@"Id"];


NSEntityDescription *speechEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Speech" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *stanford = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[stanford setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[stanford hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[stanford setValue:@"Stanford" forKey:@"speechName"];

NSManagedObject *wwdc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[wwdc setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[wwdc hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[wwdc setValue:@"WWDC" forKey:@"speechName"];

NSManagedObject *shareHolder = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[shareHolder setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[shareHolder hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[shareHolder setValue:@"Shareholder's Meeting" forKey:@"speechName"];

NSManagedObject *columbia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[columbia setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[columbia hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[columbia setValue:@"Columbia" forKey:@"speechName"];


NSMutableSet *jobsSpeeches = [steve mutableSetValueForKey:@"TycoonToSpeech"];
[jobsSpeeches addObject:stanford];
[jobsSpeeches addObject:wwdc];


NSMutableSet *warrenSpeeches = [warren mutableSetValueForKey:@"TycoonToSpeech"];
[warrenSpeeches addObject:shareHolder];
[warrenSpeeches addObject:columbia];
```

Problem 2: The main and really annoying problem, I don't know how to make didSelectRowAtIndexPath in my root view controller work so that when I click on 'Steve Jobs' in the table view, it brings up only his speeches and when I click on Warren Buffet it only brings up his speeches. I have banged my head against the wall trying to get this right. At the moment, when I click on either Steve Jobs or Warren Buffet it takes me to a new table view showing 'Steve Jobs' and 'Warren Buffet', so basically the exact same table view as the original!!! Here is my code for didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
    // Create a new table view of this very same class.
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc]
                                              initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    // Pass the managed object context
    rootViewController.context = self.context;
    NSPredicate *predicate = nil;
    // Get the object the user selected from the array
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [entityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    rootViewController.entityName = @"Speeches";

    // Create a query predicate to find all child objects of the selected object. 
    predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SpeechToTycoon == %@", selectedObject];


    [rootViewController setEntitySearchPredicate:predicate];

    //Push the new table view on the stack
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES];
    [rootViewController release];
```

Newly Edited here****

OK, here is the main code in my SpeechViewController.m file. The numberOfRowsInSection method seems to be working, but the real problem is the cellForRowAtIndexPath that is the problem. I know I am probably doing something very stupid, but I don't know what it is.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSArray *speeches = (NSArray *)tycoon.TycoonToSpeech;
// Configure the cell...
cell.textLabel.text = [[speeches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];
return cell;
```

}

**New speech view controller to language points view controller**

I added this in the app delegate to add objects to my language points entity.

```
NSEntityDescription *langPointEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LanguagePoints" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSManagedObject *pointOne = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[langPointEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[pointOne setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[pointOne hash]] forKey:@"LangId"];
[pointOne setValue:@"Drop out" forKey:@"LangPoint"];
[pointOne setValue:stanford forKey:@"LanguagePointsToSpeech"];
```

Then in my speechViewController.m file I created an NSArray called speechInfo, then here is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
LangPointsViewController *langPointsView = [[LangPointsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LangPointsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
Speech *speech = [speechInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
langPointsView.speech = speech;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:langPointsView animated:YES];
[langPointsView release];
```

I think this is where things are going wrong, I don't think I am getting the object here correctly because I do an NSLog on speech.Name in the LangPointsViewController and it comes up null, where as if I do an NSLog for tycoon.Name in the SpeechViewController it prints the person's name I clicked on. Is it the NSArray that's incorrect.

Comment: You should probably split this into two separate questions, the first one particularly is a bit of a "wall of code"

Comment: What is not working? What do you see?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Problem #1

First your relationship names are bad.  They should start with a lower case and they should simply describe what is on the other side of the relationship.  You already know where you are.  So name them `tycoon` and `speeches` respectively.  Second, because relationships are bi-directional you can construct your data easier, see the following:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObject *steve = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tycoon" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[steve setValue:@"Steve Jobs" forKey:@"Name"];
int orgId = [steve hash];
[steve setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orgId] forKey:@"Id"];

NSManagedObject *warren = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[tycoonEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[warren setValue:@"Warren Buffet" forKey:@"Name"];
int orgId2 = [warren hash];
[warren setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:orgId2] forKey:@"Id"];

NSManagedObject *stanford = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Speech" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[stanford setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[stanford hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[stanford setValue:@"Stanford" forKey:@"speechName"];
[stanford setValue:warren forKey:@"tycoon"];

NSManagedObject *wwdc = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[wwdc setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[wwdc hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[wwdc setValue:@"WWDC" forKey:@"speechName"];
[wwdc setValue:warren forKey:@"tycoon"];

NSManagedObject *shareHolder = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[shareHolder setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[shareHolder hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[shareHolder setValue:@"Shareholder's Meeting" forKey:@"speechName"];
[shareHolder setValue:warren forKey:@"tycoon"];

NSManagedObject *columbia = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[speechEntity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
[columbia setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[columbia hash]] forKey:@"speechId"];
[columbia setValue:@"Columbia" forKey:@"speechName"];
[columbia setValue:warren forKey:@"tycoon"];
```

Note that I am setting the relationship from the `Speech` side.  Core Data will handle the other side.

### Problem #2

Without looking at your entire root view controller it is hard to say what you are doing "wrong".  However, I would not re-use a view controller to display two different types of objects.  That is bad form and leads to code cruft.

Instead I would create a second "master" view controller that is designed to handle speeches.  Then you can just pass in the tycoon and your SpeechViewController can run just off an array derived from the relationship or it can build up its fetched results controller internally.  Even of greater value is the ability to customize its cells, title, etc. to fit the data it is displaying.

### Problem #3

First a comment about the new code you added:

```
SpeechViewController *speechView = [[SpeechViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpeechViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
Tycoon *tycoons = (Tycoon *)[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
speechView.tycoons = tycoons;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:speechView animated:YES];
```

There is **ZERO** reason to cast out of a `-[NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:]`.  Any method that returns `id` can be assigned to any pointer.

Casting is a lie to the compiler and should be avoided at all cost.

Now, leaving that aside, your code is fine.  I would name the property 'tycoon' instead of 'tycoons' because you are passing in a single Tycoon entity.

On the `SpeechViewController` side you can now access the speeches associated with that Tycoon entity and display them however you choose.

What is the issue you are seeing?

### Problem #4

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    NSSet *speechesSet = [[self tycoon] valueForKey:@"TycoonToSpeech"];
    // Sort the speeches
    NSSortDescriptor *nameSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedSpeeches = [speechesSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSort]];
    // Configure the cell...
    id speech = [sortedSpeeches objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[speech valueForKey:@"name"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Ok starting at the top.  First, a relationship will return a `NSSet` not a `NSArray`.  The results from a relationship are unordered.  Therefore we grab the results as a `NSSet` and then sort them.  I guessed that there is a name attribute on your `Speech` entity.

Once we have them sorted we can grab the item at the row.  This will return a `Speech` entity.  I assigned it to `id` because we are going to be using KVC anyway.

Finally, I use KVC to get the `name` attribute from the `Speech` entity and assign it to the `textLabel` of the cell.

As for your `-tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:`, that one is far simpler:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[self tycoon] valueForKey:@"TycoonToSpeech"] count];
}
```

Because you only have one section you only need to return the count of speeches.

I mentioned before that your attribute names need some work.  Since `Tycoon` is just an object and `TycoonToSpeech` is just a property on that object, the property should really be called `speeches` because it is no more special than any other property on an object.  The attribute name flows better in your code and makes your code easier to consume.  In addition, Objective-C naming conventions call for attributes aka properties to start with a lower case.

Comment: Marcus, thank you very much indeed for your help, it really cleared things up on constructing data and naming conventions! I edited my original post concerning my second problem. Any help would of course be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Marcus, very useful information. I was thinking about just using a new view controller but encountered some different information when doing research online. I have just one last question, last one, I promise, I won't take any more of your time! I edited my post above if you do have time to look at it. It is concerning assigning the array and populating the table with the appropriate text. I thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, I have been banging my head for the last couple of days over this. What a hollow head it is, because I can't get it to work properly! I know for sure the proper thing is being passed to the second view controller, but I really don't know how to get the count of the objects in the relationship in numberOfRowsInSection method and I have tried so many different ways of displaying the speeches in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but this relationship thing is just relaly confusing me. I did an NSLog on tycoon.TycoonToSpeech and it showed the proper speeches.

Comment: Show the code and let us see what is going on. A relationship is just another property, not sure what issue you are having wrapping your head around it but we hopefully seeing your code will shed some light.

Comment: Well, I have updated my original post above with my cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I know I am doing something terribly wrong and stupid, but I don't know what it is! I am happy to claim stupidity, I have never been afraid of admitting it! Please forgive the naming conventions, I just didn't want to change anything before I completely understand how it all works. I will change it afterwards!

Comment: Marcus, it worked brilliantly! No problems. It was NSSet that I did not know about. Once that was put in things worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help, you don't know the size of the headache that you cured! I will definitely study core data more and try to come to grips with its complexity. I will also be sure to get all my attribute names into proper order. Thank you once again for all your help!

Comment: What has happened? Well, thanks to your help I got things working through the displaying of the speeches. I tried to get the next step of tapping on a cell and getting to the language points of that speech, but the cell is coming up empty. Xcode isn't catching any errors in my code and the new view is loading, but nothing is being passed from the speechViewController to the LanguagePointsViewController. It is sending a (null). I added my code above if you might have a chance to take a look. Thank you for any help!!

Comment: @user997522 Is this a test project?  Can you upload it somewhere so that I can tinker with it.  This question has become very long and difficult to follow.  Perhaps open a new question with a link to the test project and send me the question url? marcus at cimgf dot com.